# "Snippet" jQuery Plugin cannot be called twice on the same element

Tags: jquery, call, code-snippets, highlighting

Well, I am building an online source code editor and I use Snippet, a jQuery Plugin to make the highlighting. So, for now I have a textarea and a pre element, where I copy the textarea 's value to pre on each keyup... So I call the function .snippet(), on document.ready() and on each keyup in order to make the syntax highlighting. But I noticed that it won't work when I call it more than once on the same element. Check my code here: http://jsfiddle.net/parisk/YkNMh/. (It won't work on keyup cause I have called it once on document.ready(), if you disable the call on document ready then it 'll work only on the first keyup)... And I would really like to solve this issue. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The snippet plugin wraps the `pre` element with a `<div>` and also adds a class to it depending on the code style you choose.

Obviously they use those to check if the element has already be *snippet*'ed.

You will need to undo those changes, and a simple solution in your case is to change

```
$('pre').snippet("c",{style:"the",showNum:true});
```

to

```
$('pre').removeClass().unwrap().snippet("c",{style:"the",showNum:true});
```

example at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/Kpphx/

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem, try catch error is: TypeError: $.browser is undefined. So after some reading on JQuery it turns out $.browser is removed in JQuery 1.9 up.

To fix add this after your JQuery link (migrate plugin):

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
```

Problem solved, hope this helps someone!